# Single Value Decomposition slight confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOUTpqlX-Xs

I was learning about Single Value Decomposition from MIT's youtube page in the link above. I understand the entire process except for something at the near end. (The question I have relates to the end of the video when he finishes the problem). When he calculates U initially, he has it multiplied by Sigma; U has a negative for the entry at the top left $(-1 \sqrt{2})$ and positive for the rest. However he then rewrites U, but this time the top left is positive now and the bottom left becomes negative. Did he write this incorrectly or am I missing an obvious step?

Comment: As was stated in the deleted answer, the switched $-$ was a typo.